# App crashes when the activity onCreate() is called on some devices

Tags: android, methods, crash, device, oncreate

Our app crashes on some devices, after loading screen.
It is running smoothly on our test devices, so we can not provide the logcat with errors.
So the only problem is that our app crashes on some devices after the method onCreate is called.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;
    screenSizeAverage = (screenWidth + screenHeight) / 2;

    this.gameStatus = 5;
    this.isEnemiesStarted = false;
    this.score = 0;
    this.playerPos = 0;

    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    bestScore = prefs.getInt("key", 0);

    gameView = new GameView(this.getApplicationContext(), this);
    gameView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(gameStatus == 1){
                    if(isEnemiesStarted == false){
                        isEnemiesStarted = true;
                    }
                    if(event.getX() < screenWidth / 2 && event.getY() < screenHeight / 2) {
                        if(playerPos != 1){
                            gameView.setPlayerPos(screenSizeAverage / 8, screenSizeAverage / 8);
                            playerPos = 1;
                            score++;
                            gameView.playSound(1);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(event.getX() > screenWidth / 2 && event.getY() < screenHeight / 2) {
                        if(playerPos != 2){
                            gameView.setPlayerPos(screenWidth - screenSizeAverage / 8 - gameView.getPlayerWidth(), screenSizeAverage / 8);
                            playerPos = 2;
                            score++;
                            gameView.playSound(1);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(event.getX() < screenWidth / 2 && event.getY() > screenHeight / 2) {
                        if(playerPos != 3){
                            gameView.setPlayerPos(screenSizeAverage / 8, screenHeight - screenSizeAverage / 8 - gameView.getPlayerWidth());
                            playerPos = 3;
                            score++;
                            gameView.playSound(1);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(event.getX() > screenWidth / 2 && event.getY() > screenHeight / 2) {
                        if(playerPos != 4){
                            gameView.setPlayerPos(screenWidth - screenSizeAverage / 8 - gameView.getPlayerWidth(), screenHeight - screenSizeAverage / 8 - gameView.getPlayerWidth());
                            playerPos = 4;
                            score++;
                            gameView.playSound(1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(gameStatus == 3){
                    if(gameView.getLoadStatus() == 2){
                        gameView.closeGameOver();
                        gameView.playSound(2);
                    }
                }
                else if(gameStatus == 4){
                    if(gameView.getLoadStatus() == 1){
                        gameView.setBestScore(bestScore);
                        gameView.setLoadStatus(2);
                    } else if(gameView.getLoadStatus() == 2){
                        gameView.restartGame();
                        gameView.setLoadStatus(0);
                        gameView.playSound(2);
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

    });
    setContentView(gameView);
```

Comment: show your code for oncreate

Comment: if you don't have error logs, paste your imports.

Comment: Use ACRA to get crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini. Problem is

```
display.getSize(size);
```

I dont know why. For me

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

works.